# TailwindCSS doesn't load styles on time

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

I've noticed a strange tailwind behavior in conjunction with Angular. When the page is loaded for the first time and all the data needs to be fetched, Tailwind's styles take a while to load, causing the user to see plain HTML without any styling. Interestingly, styles saved directly in SCSS load immediately (e.g. the green color of the spinner, visible in the upper left corner)

---

[image: View before loading Tailwind styles]
(View before loading Tailwind styles)

---

[image: View after loading Tailwind]
(View after loading Tailwind)

---

I will add that I am using Angular 15, and my tailwind configuration is as follows

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  purge: {
    content: ["./src/**/*.{html,ts}"],
  },
  theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
        md: "900px",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

When analyzing network traffic, I noticed that the "styles.36f3f1e001ffd7ec.css" file, which contains all elements added by Tailwind, is always downloaded after the JavaScript files.

[image: Network traffic]

Has anyone encountered a similar problem and might know how to solve it?

Comment: Might this be something to do with being in JIT mode?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Angular, but it looks like you use "jit" mode which compiles your styles on-demand and this can lead to some latency if you load the first time, why don't you test the default config from tailwind for Angular ?

```
 /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
     "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
        md: "900px",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

you can also check their doc for angular https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/angular